# How does $3\cdot 3^k - 3^k$ become $2 \cdot 3^k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry for the really simple question. I am trying to help my kid with her SAT practice homework.

Step 1
$$3\cdot 3^k - 3^k = m$$

Step 2
$$2 \cdot 3^k = m$$

Step 3
$$3^k = \frac{m}{2}$$

I cannot grasp how they went from Step 1 to Step 2. Can someone please explain in the most basic steps possible? Thank you in advance.

Chris

Comment: Do you know something called “take the common out” ?

Comment: Do you know that $3-1=2$ when you factor out $3^k$

Comment: $$3 x{} -x=2x$$

Comment: Or in plain words, if you have $3$ of something (anything) and remove $1$ of that something, you are left with $2$ of that something.

Comment: @Fakemistake I think there is something wrong with the prime factorization on your profile 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Oh my goodness! That was a bad typo! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For equations like this, is can often help to replace the confusing part with a simpler variable - here we could say that $$3^k=A$$

Now we can rewrite the equation so that it is $$3\cdot A-A=m$$

Hopefully it is now quite easy to see that \begin{align}3\cdot A-A&=3\cdot A-1\cdot A\\
&=(3-1)\cdot A\\
&=2\cdot A\\
&=2\cdot 3^k\end{align}

You can also just think of it as "apples" - if you have $3$ apples and you take away one apple, then you are left with $2$ apples

Comment: Thank you. This is the clearest answer. I have forgotten the rule that allows for this: 3⋅−=3⋅−1⋅. What is this rule called? I'd like to read more on it.

Comment: Do you mean substituting in $A$ for the complicated part? I don't think there is a name for it, it is just a way of making life easier. If you mean the $-A=-1\cdot A$ part, then that is simply a statement of fact, I just write out the $1$ to remind us that it is there

Comment: Yes, I meant the −=−1⋅  part. I forgot that you could do that... it's coming back to me now. Thank you!

Comment: You can also just think of it as "apples" - if you have 3 apples and you take away one apple, then you are left with 2 apples

Answer (score 0):

$ac-bc=(a-b)c$. Take $a=3,b=1$ and $c=3^{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$3\cdot3^k-3^k=(3^k+3^k+3^k)-3^k=3^k+3^k=2\cdot3^k$$

Answer (score 0):

$3^k$ is taken as common:

$3\cdot 3^k - 3^k$ = $3^k\cdot 3 - 3^k \cdot 1$ =  $3^k(3-1)$ = $3^k\cdot2$

Answer (score 0):

Here we need an assumption $k< \infty$, because $\infty-\infty$ is not defined. Then, $3 \cdot 3^k-3^k=(3-1)3^k=2 \cdot 3^k.$